# UPDATE where timestamp is the latest

Tags: sql, postgresql, logic, conditional-statements

I have a group of records all with the same data except the timestamp (Yeah, not my design)

Example:

```
record_id, user, tmstmp
1, myself, 2006-11-15 09:56:14.325882-05
1, myself, 2006-11-15 09:56:19.051823-05
1, myself, 2006-11-15 11:23:30.581366-05
etc...
```

Now I would like to UPDATE the record with the latest timestamp.  Here is what I'm trying with no luck yet:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET user = 'TESTING'
WHERE record_id = 1
ORDER BY tmstmp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The ORDER BY throws the syntax error.

I think it should be a AND condition but not seeing how.  Any thoughts?

PostgreSQL is my db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UPDATE tbl
SET user = 'TESTING'

WHERE record_id = 1

AND tms_tmp in 
(select max(tms_tmp) from tbl where record_id = 1)`

Comment: Thanks, forgot about nested selects, sheesh

Comment: Note that this will delete **multiple** rows when there are multiple rows with the same timestamp value (e.g. multiple `now()` calls in a single transaction). Also you should use `=` (equality) not the `IN` operator. It's important that you inform people of any caveats that your solutions might have.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE  mytable
SET     user = 'TESTING'
WHERE   ctid =
        (
        SELECT  ctid
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   record_id = 1
        ORDER BY
                tmstmp DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

This will correctly handle duplicates on `tmstmp`, if any.

Comment: That was really dumb of me. I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using PL/pgsql:

```
DECLARE
  cur CURSOR(key int) FOR
    SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE tbl.record_id = key ORDER BY tmstmp DESC FOR UPDATE;
BEGIN
  OPEN cur(1); -- record_id
  MOVE NEXT FROM cur;
  UPDATE tbl SET "user" = 'TESTING' WHERE CURRENT OF cur;
  CLOSE cur;
END
```

You can do this in a DO block (from version 9.0) or a function.